# Developing 32-bit C++ application in Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: c++, windows, 64-bit

I develop a Win32 application in Visual Studio 2008 (C++). It runs fine in either 32-bit or 64-bit Windows 7. However, sometimes I need to allocate quite big memory buffers (the application deals with lots of data), and if I do it in Windows 7 64-bit, it fails, in 32-bit it runs fine. By big memory buffers I mean one ~250MB and another ~150MB. I have 8GB RAM installed in my PC, and according to my information, the 64-bit OS makes 4GB availabla for a 32-bit application. I need nowhere near that limit, still malloc fails.
Any ideas why and what can I do about it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Allocate smaller blocks and piece them together to present a single larger *virtual* block of memory.

Comment: You aren't using HeapCreate and specifying a maximum size by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

150MB and 250MB are not especially huge allocations.  As others have noted, the problem you are hitting is most likely address space fragmentation (i.e. there is enough free space, it's just not all in one piece).

In addition to the other suggestions:

- Allocate the memory as soon as the program starts.  The address space will be less likely to be fragmented.  If it wouldn't be sensible to allocate this much memory for the life of the program, use [VirtualAlloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the `MEM_RESERVE` flag to reserve the address space and commit it later.
- If address space is fragmented as soon as the process starts, it's probably caused by DLLs loading at unhelpful locations.  You can use [VMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533) to see what's happening in the address space.  If DLLs belonging to you are fragmenting the address space you can rebase them.

Comment: I cannot allocate all the buffers at the start, these big buffers I only need for converting something, at the end of which I free them. Fragmentation could be one of the reasons though. How can I rebase my DLL? Thanks.

Comment: As I said, you can reserve the address space without actually allocating the memory using VirtualAlloc.  Anyway, you can set a DLL base address with the `link /BASE` option.  This appears in VS under the advanced linker options.  Or you can use `editbin /REBASE` to modify an existing DLL.

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting virtual address space limit in your Win32 binary. The limit [might be 2 to 4 GB depending on OS and environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366912%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Actualy limit is less due to allocation fragmentation.

Your choices are to:

- live within space you can effectively allocate
- move to x64
- use multiple processes
- use memory allocation API which allows unmapping/re-mapping blocks into application virtual address space, see [File Mappings: Virtual Memory and Virtual Address Space](http://alax.info/blog/1325) for details on this

Comment: I have an x64 version and of course it does not give me the same trouble, but I would like to keep the x86 version as well. For some reason, it seems to me that memory management works better for an x86 app with 32-bit Win7 than with 64-bit Win7.

Comment: If you compile your `Win32` binary with `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` option, your app is going to immediately work *way* better in 64-bit OS - it is going to receive 4 GB immediately there as compared to original 2 GB and maximal possible 3 GB in 32-bit system.

Comment: That is what I thought. I do compile with Largeaddressaware, yet I run out of memory sooner than I would in a 32-bit OS. (To be honest, I am not quite sure, since I compared 64-bit Win7 to 32-bit XP).

Comment: I think that by saying "I need nowhere near that limit" you are missing something. And you can also use metrics more precise than "sooner" or "later". You have *Performance Monitor* and *Process Explorer* (not to mention the API) that show you exactly how much of virtual space is used. You can even step through your allocations and see how much each one grabs out.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is a bug in malloc under win7-64.  I have run the same tests with my 32-bit app on three machines: XP32, w7-32 and win7-64.  It runs OK on the 32bit platforms but fails to allocate a 110Mb block under w7-64.  I have de-fragmented my drive and tried again from a clean reboot with the same result.

K

Comment: Why would defragmenting your drive enable you to allocate more memory via `malloc`?  Also which compiler?  The OP states he is using VS2K8 but you make no such claims.

Comment: I am using Silverfrost's FTN95 compiler and their internal "GET_STORAGE" function, which apparently calls GlobalAlloc (apologies - I thought it called malloc directly).  I defragged my drive just in case there wasn't enough contiguous space in the virtual memory to succeed.

Comment: (a) malloc calls GlobalAlloc or an equivalent, not the other way around; (b) virtual memory doesn't work that way, it makes absolutely no difference whether the file is contiguous on disk or not.

Comment: OK, being an 'umble Fortran programmer means all this "windahs-malarkey" is a bit beyond me.  All the above doesn't explain why my app runs successfully on 32-bit platforms but not on a 64-bit machine, where, if I understand correctly, memory allocation should be less of a problem!

Comment: OK, the FTN95 linker has a /3GB switch.  Using this solves the problem (although I'm pretty sure the app has only requested about 350Mb at the time it fails)